# how to check the pause image download address

Tags: kubernetes, containerd

I have changed the kubernetes default pause image download address to `registry.cn-hangzhou.aliyuncs.com/google_containers/pause:3.6` in `/etc/containerd/config.toml` like this:

```
[root@k8sslave01 kubelet]# cat /etc/containerd/config.toml
#   Copyright 2018-2022 Docker Inc.

#   Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
#   you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
#   You may obtain a copy of the License at

#       http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

#   Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
#   distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
#   WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
#   See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
#   limitations under the License.

#disabled_plugins = ["cri"]

#root = "/var/lib/containerd"
#state = "/run/containerd"
#subreaper = true
#oom_score = 0
[plugins."io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri".registry]
   config_path = "/etc/containerd/certs.d"

[plugins."io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri"]
  #sandbox_image = "k8s.m.daocloud.io/pause:3.6"
  sandbox_image = "registry.cn-hangzhou.aliyuncs.com/google_containers/pause:3.6"

#[grpc]
#  address = "/run/containerd/containerd.sock"
#  uid = 0
#  gid = 0

#[debug]
#  address = "/run/containerd/debug.sock"
#  uid = 0
#  gid = 0
#  level = "info"
```

This is the official document I am followed to https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/container-runtimes/#override-pause-image-containerd. Then restart the containerd, but now I found the pause image did not download from the new address, seems the override address did not work. Am I missing something? what should I do to make the override address work? This is the containerd running status:

```
[root@k8sslave01 kubelet]# systemctl status containerd
● containerd.service - containerd container runtime
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/containerd.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (running) since Mon 2024-02-19 13:11:30 CST; 10min ago
     Docs: https://containerd.io
  Process: 9709 ExecStartPre=/sbin/modprobe overlay (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 9711 (containerd)
    Tasks: 164
   Memory: 563.7M
   CGroup: /system.slice/containerd.service
           ├─2070 /usr/bin/containerd-shim-runc-v2 -namespace k8s.io -id 85bb2d9e9ad97fcef48745279e396aaaac8677f02c72efa85a78eabe33764529 -address /run/containerd/containerd.sock
           ├─2088 /usr/bin/containerd-shim-runc-v2 -namespace k8s.io -id 879cd87bf469b8966730fec490269673b46221acdc68685fb1213379616e8d08 -address /run/containerd/containerd.sock
           ├─2131 /usr/bin/containerd-shim-runc-v2 -namespace k8s.io -id d1a1220b677c9df2016dbdbe89a96778bb088af009bf9fe991b75f0260c27dfd -address /run/containerd/containerd.sock
           ├─2164 /usr/bin/containerd-shim-runc-v2 -namespace k8s.io -id 62f0f6b1e966f977d1384c57302840319f4e20f075761cba6f62e5e651bb6952 -address /run/containerd/containerd.sock
           ├─3579 /usr/bin/containerd-shim-runc-v2 -namespace k8s.io -id 949a8f4a46bb1dcce10054af8eaba77906d2fc746dcf3a295b69f41274968bd9 -address /run/containerd/containerd.sock
           ├─9711 /usr/bin/containerd
           ├─kubepods-besteffort-podf5b81dee_42cf_4c80_8927_239a45cbf0fb.slice:cri-containerd:144eb54ca91511a50c4f31a82bb18d1da1267650193f72d5eaac6adec4cac029
           │ └─3707 /usr/bin/promtail -config.file=/etc/promtail/promtail.yaml
           ├─kubepods-besteffort-podf5b81dee_42cf_4c80_8927_239a45cbf0fb.slice:cri-containerd:949a8f4a46bb1dcce10054af8eaba77906d2fc746dcf3a295b69f41274968bd9
           │ └─3599 /pause
           ├─kubepods-besteffort-poda668fff9_1320_40b2_a9b1_f04f721b6b16.slice:cri-containerd:54e9858d309cedfee9975af9e21c71ddfdd1ef479c6efe97369cbd9c5a253e9f
           │ └─2254 /usr/local/bin/kube-proxy --config=/var/lib/kube-proxy/config.conf --hostname-override=k8sslave01
           ├─kubepods-burstable-podff9b5985_0a25_4361_bcfe_f5eddbc4cef5.slice:cri-containerd:765d6d3050cd0cb37acf7f88b68b40adeebf9abae24b77e7329b7e819cdf4431
           │ ├─25676 cilium-agent --config-dir=/tmp/cilium/config-map
           │ └─29950 cilium-health-responder --listen 4240 --pidfile /var/run/cilium/state/health-endpoint.pid
           ├─kubepods-burstable-podff9b5985_0a25_4361_bcfe_f5eddbc4cef5.slice:cri-containerd:62f0f6b1e966f977d1384c57302840319f4e20f075761cba6f62e5e651bb6952
           │ └─2202 /pause
           ├─kubepods-besteffort-podd1ff8e59_2b3c_4baf_bd98_4ce750f4e1ac.slice:cri-containerd:879cd87bf469b8966730fec490269673b46221acdc68685fb1213379616e8d08
           │ └─2141 /pause
           ├─kubepods-besteffort-poda668fff9_1320_40b2_a9b1_f04f721b6b16.slice:cri-containerd:85bb2d9e9ad97fcef48745279e396aaaac8677f02c72efa85a78eabe33764529
           │ └─2116 /pause
           ├─kubepods-besteffort-podd1ff8e59_2b3c_4baf_bd98_4ce750f4e1ac.slice:cri-containerd:bff2d1eba164983b1a6da78ee6af561f0854f933ecc8728146b0a812642e2851
           │ └─12221 /bin/node_exporter --path.procfs=/host/proc --path.sysfs=/host/sys --path.rootfs=/host/root --path.udev.data=/host/root/run/udev/data --web.listen-address=[0.0.0.0]:9101
           ├─kubepods-besteffort-pod19058bec_ec59_4c9a_b98e_066e7259d7ce.slice:cri-containerd:d1a1220b677c9df2016dbdbe89a96778bb088af009bf9fe991b75f0260c27dfd
           │ └─2188 /pause
           └─kubepods-besteffort-pod19058bec_ec59_4c9a_b98e_066e7259d7ce.slice:cri-containerd:bd00a1ad428d5823a48518861959f2e499d3357cdd810dfb6a2efe04fe3b08f7
             └─28261 cilium-operator-generic --config-dir=/tmp/cilium/config-map --debug=false
```

and this is the containerd version info:

```
[root@k8sslave01 kubelet]# containerd -v
containerd containerd.io 1.6.24 61f9fd88f79f081d64d6fa3bb1a0dc71ec870523
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run the "crictl info|grep pause" command to get it, it should looks like bellow:

```
# crictl info|grep pause
    "sandboxImage": "registry.cn-hangzhou.aliyuncs.com/rancher/mirrored-pause:3.6",
```

For your /etc/containerd/config.toml file, you can try to modify it like below:

```
[plugins]
  [plugins."cri"]
      sandbox_image = "registry.cn-hangzhou.aliyuncs.com/google_containers/pause:3.6"
```

after that you shoud run systemctl restart containerd to apply it.

Comment: I check the image but it still look like this: `[root@k8sslave01 ~]# crictl info|grep pause
    "sandboxImage": "registry.k8s.io/pause:3.6",`, Am I missing something?